# HTML title attribute line break

Tags: html, sql-server

I am trying to generate a tool tip text using SQL. The text generated is passed as Title Attribute in HTML. There needs to be some newline characters generated in the tool tip.
I have used the following - `&#10;` `CHAR(13)`; `CHAR(10)`; `<br>`; `\n`.
However in all cases, I see the character itself in HTML and not a new line.
Any idea how to achieve this?

the SQL is something like this

````
   (SELECT
      STUFF(';' + WOR.OrderNo + ' - ' + P.ProductNo + ' - ' + CAST(CAST(ROUND(WOR.OrderQuantity , 0) as int) as varchar(20)) + '; <br/> ', 1, 1, '') 
       FROM
          [ORDER] WOR 
          JOIN
             PRODUCT P 
             ON P.ID = WOR.ProductID 
          JOIN
             PRODUCT_GROUP PGR 
             ON P.ID = PGR.ProductID FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)')```

And the Tootip that I see is the following

```SMU_100000021 - A-WHEL-001 - 100;<br/>SMU_100000023 - A-WHEL-001 - 90;<br/>```
````

Comment: Show us the code. The correct markup for a new line, in HTML, would be `<br />` so if that isn't working, you need to show us why.

Comment: Put it in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Also, if you're using strings like `'<br>'` and `FOR XML PATH`, the value will be escaped to `'&lt;br&gt;'` if you're including Markup in a `FOR XML PATH` statement, you need to use the `TYPE` operator.

Comment: this the updated code - SELECT
(SELECT
   STUFF(';' + WOR.OrderNo + ' - ' + P.ProductNo + ' - ' + CAST(CAST(ROUND(WOR.OrderQuantity , 0) as int) as varchar(20)) + '; <br/> ', 1, 1, '') 
FROM
   [ORDER] WOR 
   JOIN
      PRODUCT P 
      ON P.ID = WOR.ProductID 
   JOIN
      PRODUCT_GROUP PGR 
      ON P.ID = PGR.ProductID FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)')                                                                       The  title is rendered asL  SMU_100000021 - A-WHEL-001 - 100;<br/>SMU_100000023 - A-WHEL-001 - 90;<br/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CHAR(10) did the trick.

```
(SELECT
      STUFF(';' + WOR.OrderNo + ' - ' + P.ProductNo + ' - ' + CAST(CAST(ROUND(WOR.OrderQuantity , 0) as int) as varchar(20))  +' '+ CHAR(10) + ' ', 1, 1, '') 
       FROM
          [ORDER] WOR 
          JOIN
             PRODUCT P 
             ON P.ID = WOR.ProductID 
          JOIN
             PRODUCT_GROUP PGR 
             ON P.ID = PGR.ProductID FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)')
```